ElectronWininstaller : Installation Failed | Squirrel
I am making a small software for a game, and I have this error when I want to open my setup.exe:
Installation Failed
There was an error while installing the application.

Check the setup log for more information and contact the author.

Error File (SquirrelSetup.log).
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:17> Program: Starting Squirrel Updater: --install .
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:17> Program: Starting install, writing to C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\SquirrelTemp
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:17> Program: About to install to: C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:17> SingleGlobalInstance: Grabbing lockfile with timeout of 00:00:10
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:17> CheckForUpdateImpl: Reading RELEASES file from C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\SquirrelTemp
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:18> CheckForUpdateImpl: Remote version 1.0.9147 differs from local 
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:18> CheckForUpdateImpl: First run or local directory is corrupt, starting from scratch
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:18> ApplyReleasesImpl: Writing files to app directory: C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:19> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\lib\net45\chrome_100_percent.pak to C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\chrome_100_percent.pak
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:19> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\lib\net45\d3dcompiler_47.dll to C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\d3dcompiler_47.dll
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:19> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\lib\net45\app.ico to C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\app.ico
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:19> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\lib\net45\chrome_200_percent.pak to C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\chrome_200_percent.pak
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:19> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\lib\net45\Discord.exe to C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\Discord.exe
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:20> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\lib\net45\Discord.exe.sig to C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\Discord.exe.sig
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:20> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\lib\net45\ffmpeg.dll to C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\ffmpeg.dll
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:20> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\lib\net45\icudtl.dat to C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\icudtl.dat
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:20> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\lib\net45\installer.db to C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\installer.db
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:20> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\lib\net45\libEGL.dll to C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\libEGL.dll
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:20> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\lib\net45\libGLESv2.dll to C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\libGLESv2.dll
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:20> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\lib\net45\updater.node to C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\updater.node
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:20> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\lib\net45\snapshot_blob.bin to C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\snapshot_blob.bin
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:20> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\lib\net45\resources.pak to C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\resources.pak
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:20> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\lib\net45\v8_context_snapshot.bin to C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\v8_context_snapshot.bin
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:20> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\lib\net45\vk_swiftshader_icd.json to C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\vk_swiftshader_icd.json
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:20> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\lib\net45\vk_swiftshader.dll to C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\vk_swiftshader.dll
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:20> ApplyReleasesImpl: Moving file C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\lib\net45\vulkan-1.dll to C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\vulkan-1.dll
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:20> ApplyReleasesImpl: Squirrel Enabled Apps: [C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\Discord.exe]
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:20> Utility: Process Started: C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\Discord.exe --squirrel-install 1.0.9147, pid 32160
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:21> Utility: Received exitcode 0 from process C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\Discord.exe
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:21> ApplyReleasesImpl: ran C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9147\Discord.exe, pid 22872
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:21> ApplyReleasesImpl: Starting fixPinnedExecutables
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:21> ApplyReleasesImpl: fixPinnedExecutables: newCurrentFolder: app-1.0.9147
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:21> ApplyReleasesImpl: fixPinnedExecutables: enumerating path C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu failed: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: L'accès au chemin d'accès 'C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programmes' est refusé.
   à System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   à System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.AddSearchableDirsToStack(SearchData localSearchData)
   à System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   à System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   à System.IO.DirectoryInfo.InternalGetFiles(String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
   à System.IO.DirectoryInfo.GetFiles(String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption)
   à Squirrel.UpdateManager.ApplyReleasesImpl.fixPinnedExecutables(SemanticVersion newCurrentVersion)
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:21> ApplyReleasesImpl: Updating shortcut C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\Desktop\Discord.lnk
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:21> ApplyReleasesImpl: Fixing up tray icons
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:21> ApplyReleasesImpl: cleanDeadVersions: for version 1.0.9147
26372> 2024-06-02 11:40:21> ApplyReleasesImpl: cleanDeadVersions: exclude current version folder app-1.0.9147
24104> 2024-06-02 11:40:22> Program: Starting Squirrel Updater: --install .
24104> 2024-06-02 11:40:22> Program: Starting install, writing to C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\SquirrelTemp
24104> 2024-06-02 11:40:22> Program: RELEASES doesn't exist, creating it at C:\Users\MYUSERNAME\AppData\Local\SquirrelTemp\RELEASES
24104> 2024-06-02 11:40:22> Unhandled exception: System.AggregateException: Une ou plusieurs erreurs se sont produites. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: La séquence ne contient aucun élément.
   à System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   à Squirrel.Update.Program.<Install>d__5.MoveNext()
   --- Fin de la trace de la pile d'exception interne ---
   à System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   à System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   à System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   à Squirrel.Update.Program.executeCommandLine(String[] args)
   à Squirrel.Update.Program.main(String[] args)
---> (Exception interne #0) System.InvalidOperationException: La séquence ne contient aucun élément.
   à System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   à Squirrel.Update.Program.<Install>d__5.MoveNext()<---

Thank's !
My build.js
const electronInstaller = require("electron-winstaller");
const path = require("path");

const appDirectory = path.join(
  __dirname,
  "release-builds",
  "ogbridge-win32-x64"
);
const outputDirectory = path.join(__dirname, "installers");

electronInstaller
  .createWindowsInstaller({
    appDirectory: appDirectory,
    outputDirectory: outputDirectory,
    authors: "OGHub.fr",
    exe: "ogbridge.exe",
    setupExe: "ogbridge-Setup.exe",
    noMsi: true,
    iconUrl: path.join(__dirname, "app", "img", "logo.ico"),
    setupIcon: path.join(__dirname, "app", "img", "logo.ico"),
    // Sign the installer and executable
    signWithParams:
      '/f "./certifs/certificate.pfx" /p "OGBridgeApp00001" /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /fd sha256',
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Installateur Windows créé avec succès!");
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(
      `Erreur lors de la création de l'installateur : ${error.message}`
    );
  });

Console.log send "Successfull Windows.."
so I don't know where my mistake might be.
I've heard that Discord etc should be deleted because they also use Squirrel.
